# How to type the StaticRouterContext from react-router-dom in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, server-side-rendering

I'm doing SSR for my app (for robots only).

The render of the `<App/>` might result in a not found route.

I need to detect when that render ends in a `NOT_FOUND` route so I can return a `res.sendStatus(404);` from my `express` server.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/static-router) from the official docs of `react-router`.

I have a "catch all" route, that will render a 404 Page and will add that information to the `staticContext`:

**AllRoutes.ts**

```
<Route exact path={"*"} render={({ staticContext }) => { 
  if (staticContext) {
    staticContext.statusCode = 404;
  }
  return <Page404/>;
}}/>
```

The type inferred for the `staticContext` object inside the `render` prop of the `Route` component is:

[image]

And it seems that its only property is an optional `statusCode?: number` property.

[image]

**On the SERVER side, this is what I do:**

**ssrApp.tsx**

```
import App from "@src/App";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom";

// ...

const context = {};  // <<< WHAT TO TYPE THIS VARIABLE ?

const appHtml = renderToString(
  <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
    <App/>
  </StaticRouter>
);

res.status(context.statusCode || 200).send(appHtml);
```

The type for the `context` prop of the `<StaticRouter>` component is `StaticRouterContext`:

[image]

It accepts the empty `const context= {};` prop. But it complains when I try to access the `statusCode` property out of it.

[image]

---

All the types mentioned here seem to come from the package `@types/react-router` or `@types/react-router-dom`, not really sure which one.

**@types/react-router/index.d.ts**

```
export interface StaticContext {
    statusCode?: number;
}

export interface RouteComponentProps<
    Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {},
    C extends StaticContext = StaticContext,
    S = H.LocationState
> {
    history: H.History<S>;
    location: H.Location<S>;
    match: match<Params>;
    staticContext?: C;
}
```

How can I type my `context` object? So far, I haven't been able to import the `StaticRouterContext` or `StaticContext` from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a way to handle this.

I only have installed the following packages:

```
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5" (AS DEV DEPENDENCY)
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"        (AS REGULAR DEPENDENCY)
```

I'm not able to import the types I've mentioned in the question because they are defined in `@types/react-router`, which is a inner dependency of `@types/react-router-dom`, and they are not re-exported from the latter.

Here are the types from `@types/react-router` that are re-exported from `@types/react-router-dom`:

**@types/react-router-dom/index.d.ts**

[image]

What I was able to do:

I've created my own `MY_STATIC_CONTEXT` type, which needs to implicitly extends the `StaticContext` type defined in `@types/react-router` which is used in `StaticRouter` and `RouteProps`.

This is the `StaticContext` type from `@types/react-router`:

```
export interface StaticContext {
    statusCode?: number;
}
```

So I did:

```
type MY_STATIC_CONTEXT = {
  statusCode?: number        // THIS IS SO YOU EXTEND THE ORIGINAL TYPE,
  ROUTE_NOT_FOUND: boolean   // THIS IS MY CUSTOM PROP
}
```

Now, this is possible:

**ON_CLIENT - AllRoutes.ts**

A simple type assention allows me to updated my custom prop `ROUTE_NOT_FOUND`.

```
<Route exact path={"*"} render={({ staticContext }) => { 
  if (staticContext) {
    (staticContext as MY_STATIC_CONTEXT).statusCode = 404; 
    (staticContext as MY_STATIC_CONTEXT).ROUTE_NOT_FOUND = true;
  }
  return <Error404/>;
}}/>
```

**ON_SERVER - ssrApp.tsx**

```
const context: MY_STATIC_CONTEXT = {
  ROUTE_NOT_FOUND: false
};

const appHtml = renderToString(
  <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
      <App/>
  </StaticRouter>
));

if (context.ROUTE_NOT_FOUND) {
  // DO SOMETHING
}

res.status(context.statusCode || 200).send(appHtml);
```